# How to measure process memory usage in given moment

Tags: python, memory

Here is the way to measure peak memory usage of current process since the start of the process.

```
process= psutil.Process(os.getpid())
process.memory_full_info().peak_wset
```

But what if I want to do few measurements for different parts(functions) of the program? How can I get memory used by program in any desired moment to check difference before and after?
Maybe there is the way to reset peak_wset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you no longer need `os.getpid()` when inspecting current process.  Just use `psutil.Process()`

**1) To measure if the peak memory increased or not (never decreased) before a function call, invoke this before and after a function call and take the difference:**

- On Windows:

  - `psutil.Process().memory_info().peak_wset`
  - `psutil.Process().memory_full_info().peak_wset`
- On Linux:

  - I read [here](https://programtalk.com/python-examples/psutil.Process.memory_info_ex.peak_wset/) the `resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss` would do the trick but I haven't tested.

**2) To measure the current memory variation before and after a function call, invoke it before and after a function call and take the difference:**

- On Windows and Linux:

  - `psutil.Process().memory_info().rss`
  - `psutil.Process().memory_full_info().rss`
  - `psutil.Process().memory_full_info().uss`

From [docs](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.memory_full_info):

> **`memory_full_info()`** returns the same information as **`memory_info()`**, plus, on some platform (Linux, macOS, Windows), also provides additional metrics (USS, PSS and swap). The additional metrics provide a better representation of “effective” process memory consumption (in case of USS) as explained in detail in this blog post. It does so by passing through the whole process address. As such it usually requires higher user privileges than **`memory_info()`** and is considerably slower. On platforms where extra fields are not implemented this simply returns the same metrics as **`memory_info()`**.
>
> **`uss`** (Linux, macOS, Windows): aka “Unique Set Size”, this is the memory which is unique to a process and which would be freed if the process was terminated right now.
>
> **Note**: **`uss`** is probably the most representative metric for determining how much memory is actually being used by a process.

**3) To measure the specific memory a function call used during its execution, before any garbage collection takes place, you need a [memory profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+memory+profiling).**